# Sheet rock in home garages

Tags: drywall

Is there a standard for installing sheet rock in garages that are attached to homes. The builder told me that they don't finish sheet rock in garages the same as inside homes. My home is a new build. 
Sheet rock in garage is a mess.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean by "a mess"? A photograph would really help.

Comment: I don't know what the standard is (so comment rather than an answer). But I have seen that plenty of places (Maryland, USA) where the original drywall in the garage typically has minimal patching/rough sanding over the seams but not fully finished and not painted at all. Not "a mess" but not a finished look.

Comment: The reason that attached garages are usually only taped/mudded is because in most areas, an attached garage has to be 100% sealed to prevent carbon monoxide from a running vehicle entering the living premises. To save time and money, builders often just slap the mud on with no sanding/tidying and forgo any painting.

Answer (score 3):

> Sheet rock in garage is a mess.

That is the standard, unless your contract specified an interior quality finish. It will be taped and mudded and possibly given a coat of paint.

The good news is that you can practice sanding and finishing and texturing drywall in your garage with no fear of messing it up.